# primefaces add another components to datatable paginator template

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have primefaces datatable with defined paginator template and toolbar in `<f:facet name="header">`

example:

```
<p:dataTable paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
currentPageReportTemplate="{startRecord} - {endRecord} of {totalRecords}">

<f:facet name="header">

    <p:selectOneMenu id="presetSelectOneMenu"
        value="#{alarmTable.selectedGuiPreset}"
        style="padding: 0; margin: 0;float: left; display: block; width: 100px; text-align: left;">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Global" itemValue="" itemDisabled="true" />
        <f:selectItems value="#{guiSettings.arrayOfGlobalGuiPresets}" />
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Personal" itemValue="" itemDisabled="true" />
        <f:selectItems value="#{guiSettings.arrayOfPersonalGuiPresets}" />
        <p:ajax event="change" update="alarmTableId"
            listener="#{alarmTable.actionSelectGuiPreset(true)}" />
    </p:selectOneMenu>

    <p:commandButton id="btnRefreshFilter" icon="ui-icon-refresh"
        action="#{alarmTable.actionSelectGuiPreset(true)}"
        update="alarmTableId" style="margin-left: 3px; float: left;"
        title="Refresh" />

    <h:outputText id="selectedGuiPresetText"
        style="float: left; font-size: 12px; padding-top: 3px; padding-left: 5px"
        value="In use - '#{alarmTable.selectedGuiPresets.size() > 0 ? alarmTable.selectedGuiPresets.get(0).presetName : ''}'" />
</f:facet>
<p:columns>
```

it's looks like: [pic](http://goo.gl/MevqZ)

I want save vertical monitor space and integrate components from`<f:facet name="header">` into paginator row.
Is that possible?

Answer (score 5):

It is indeed possible as of PrimeFaces 5.0 (community edition). You are now able to define a custom facet and add its name to the `paginatorTemplate`. Like this:

```
<p:dataTable paginator="true" paginatorTemplate="{Customization}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}">

    <f:facet name="{Customization}">
        <p:selectOneMenu ... />
        <p:commandButton ... />
        <h:outputText ... />
    </f:facet>

    ...header
    ...columns
</p:dataTable>
```

A demonstration of this feature can be found in the [DataExporter showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/dataexporter/basic.xhtml).

Regards

Comment: How can I make this custom facet move to the right hand side?

Comment: Just put it to the end of the list, like so: `paginatorTemplate="{FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}  {Customization}"`. If you want your facet to appear right bounded you could possibly add `style="float: right"` to your component, but that's untested.

Comment: Hi, I am using primefaces 5.3 and myfaces. When I use the `{Customization}` facet, I face the exception:
`Subsequent characters of component identifier must be a letter, a digit, an underscore ('_'), or a dash ('-')! But component identifier contains "{"`

Comment: I tried removing curly brackets in both facet name and paginator template and it worked.