# Is it possible to paginate a p:dataTable based on a column's data?

Tags: primefaces

I'm using Primfaces to display a set of tabular data. Is it possible to paginate the dataSource so that, for example, page 1 contains the Customers whose name starts with "A", page 2 with Customers whose name starts with "B" and so on...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no build in feature for that.

What you need to do is:

1. Use the LazyDataModel with a custom filter map: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/lazy.xhtml |
2. Add something to select the letter e.q. p:commandLink for each letter and maybe an option to show all or a selectOneMenu. (Look at my note at the end if you really want to map 1 to A and so on). Edit your paginator template like this: [primefaces add another components to datatable paginator template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15405208/primefaces-add-another-components-to-datatable-paginator-template)
3. A class which extends the LazyDataModel by a String which saves the selected letter
4. Each click should send the value to your LazyDataModel and refresh the table
5. In the load method of your LazyDataModel you could either edit your database query and filter by the selected letter to get the correct list or if you don't have a database connection filter the list in your java code.
6. If you don't want an additional pagination, sortBy or filter turn it off.
7. If you don't turn the filter off for the customer name take care of additional filters on the customer name which could be set too.

**Note**: You could also map the page to the letter if you really want 1 to be A and 2 to be B and so on. Then you just need to calculate which page the user requests by using first and pageSize of the LazyDataModel and set the filter for the appropriate letter.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'll try it!